# Difference between != and <>?

Tags: python

I just saw some code using the <> operator (don't know what this is called) instead of the != operator in Python. Is there any difference between the two or do they mean the same thing? What's the <> operator called? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<>` operator is considered obsolete:

https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in